# Image's size in Button doesn't format correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have the following code

The image is shown properly at Chrome and Firefox but on the Internet Explorer the image seems huge. What adjustments should I do to see the same image size on every browser?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>mytitle</title>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#maths_modal">
                <figure>
                    <img src="https://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                    <figcaption>Caption under my image</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </button>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

(The error persists even without the figure element)

Comment: can you please add css code?

Comment: The whole code is the code I uploaded on the question. The only css using is from the online bootstrap.min.css
Take the code and try it on IE and Chrome to see the issue

Comment: then which internet explorer version do you have? I'm using a Mac, hence no IE.

Comment: I use Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common issue with Bootstrap 3 and IE11, try this in your css file:

```
.img-responsive {width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found a workaround on this problem
Since in bootstrap `<button>` and `<a>` can both act the same, I replaced `<button>` with `<a>` and the compatibility issue was solved